# Select unique values from a list of 3

Tags: r

I would like to list all unique combinations of vectors of length 3 where each element of the vector can range between 1 to 9.

First I list all such combinations:

```
df <- expand.grid(1:9, 1:9, 1:9)
```

Then I would like to remove the rows that contain repetitions.
For example:

```
1 1 9
9 1 1
1 9 1
```

should only be included once.

In other words if two lines have the same numbers and the same number of each number then it should only be included once.

Note that 
`8 8 8` or 
`9 9 9` is fine as long as it only appears once.

Comment: In your example, which one should be included?

Comment: it doesn't matter either of the 3

Comment: perhaps `gtools::combinations(9, 3, repeats.allowed = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Instead of `expand.grid`, I believe you can use `utils:combn(1:9,3)` to get unique combinations of `1:9` taken `3` at a time.

Comment: @aichao this method does not included cases like 9 9 9 or 9 9 2

Comment: @user2733997 Then use what `mtoto` suggests with repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your approach and the idea to remove repetitions:

```
df <- expand.grid(1:2, 1:2, 1:2)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    1    1    1
# 2    2    1    1
# 3    1    2    1
# 4    2    2    1
# 5    1    1    2
# 6    2    1    2
# 7    1    2    2
# 8    2    2    2    
df2 <- unique(t(apply(df, 1, sort))) #class matrix
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    2
# [3,]    1    2    2
# [4,]    2    2    2
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2) #class data.frame
```

There are probably more efficient methods, but if I understand you correct, that is the result you want.

Comment: In case of `expand.grid(1:3, 1:3, 1:3)`, does not produce all cases.

Comment: Which one is missing? I get 10 results for ``1:3``, 3 for 3times the same, 6 for 2times the same, and 1 for 3different.

Comment: I thought the OP wanted them to be removed as they have just a different order. See his example with 1-1-9, 9-1-1, 1-9-1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (since your data frame is not large, so it does not pain!):

```
len <- apply(df,1,function(x) length(unique(x)))
res <- rbind(df[len!=2,], df[unique(apply(df[len==2,],1,prod)),])
```

Here is what is done:

1. Get the number of unique elements per row
2. Comprises two steps:

   - First argument of `rbind`: Those with length either 1 (e.g. `1 1 1`, `7 7 7`, etc) or 3 (e.g. `5 8 7`, `2 4 9`, etc) are included in the final results `res`.
   - Second argument of `rbind`: For those in which the number of unique elements are `2` (e.g. `1 1 9`, `3 5 3`, etc), we apply product per row and take whose unique products (cause, for example, the product of `3 3 5` and `3 5 3` and `5 3 3` are the same)